# The difference between np.function and function

Tags: python, numpy

We can import numpy and use its functions directly as:

```
from numpy import *

a = arraay([1,2,3]) # and it works well.
```

Why do some people use the following method?

```
import numpy as np

a= np.array([1,2,3])
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad

Comment: The second import is better in case some libraries have the same function names -- it keeps the namespaces separate and clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is easy: `from numpy import *` imports all names from the top-level NumPy module into your current "module" (namespace). `import numpy as np` will just make that top-level NumPy module available if you use `np.xxx`.

However there is one reason why you shouldn't use `from any_module import *`: It may just overwrite existing names. For example NumPy has its own `any`, `max`, `all` and `min` functions, which will happily shadow the built-in Python `any`, `max`, ... functions (a *very* common "gotcha").

My advise: Avoid `from numpy import *` even if it seems like less effort than typing `np.` all the time!

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of neatness but also consistency: you might have multiple functions with the same name from different modules (for instance there's a function called "random" in Numpy, but also in other packages like SciPy) so it's important to denote which exact function you're using from which exact module. [This link](https://shahriar.svbtle.com/importing-star-in-python) has a great explanation and makes the point about code readability as well.